# Mostrar Loading al cargar url en clase mplayer

Tags: android

Estimados muy buenos días, soy bastante novato en el desarrollo de aplicaciones móviles, estoy aprendiendo y necesito poder mostrar un loading después de lanzar mi primera imagen de la app en un Splash.

Es decir, tengo una app que al iniciar se lanza un Splash, esta dura aproximadamente 2 segundos, por mientras se carga una url que contiene el streaming que debo reproducir al iniciar la app, tarda un tiempo en cargar esta url y durante ese instante deseo mostrar un loading, cómo lo puedo hacer?

Este es mi código final.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
  static MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    ImageButton buttonPlay;
    ImageButton buttonStop;
    String url = "url";
    Button btn_politica, btn_deportes, btn_espectaculo, btn_entretencion;
    ProgressBar progressbar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);//analiza el archivo XML, traduce a objetos cada componente,
        progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.mi_loading);
        onPrepared(mPlayer);
        //le asigna los atributos, establece contenedores y todas las relaciones
        //padre e hijo necesarias.

        //Bloque de coding para el streaming al cargar el activity
        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            mPlayer.prepare();

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        mPlayer.start();
       //Finaliza bloque de codigo para cargar el streaming al inicio de la aplicacion+

        initialize();

        //Bloque de codigo para el streaming al presionar play
        buttonPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play);
        buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View v) {
                mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                try {
                    mPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    mPlayer.prepare();
                   // progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.mi_loading);
                    //progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                mPlayer.start();
               // progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                buttonPlay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                buttonStop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        });

        //Bloque de codigo para el streaming al presionar pause
        buttonStop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.stop);
        buttonStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (mPlayer != null && mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mPlayer.stop();
                    //buttonPlay.setEnabled(true);
                    buttonPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    buttonStop.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }

        });

    }
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
    {
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    private void initialize() {
        btn_deportes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn_deportes.setOnClickListener(this);

        btn_politica = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btn_politica.setOnClickListener(this);

        btn_espectaculo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        btn_espectaculo.setOnClickListener(this);

        btn_entretencion = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        btn_entretencion.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity_Noticias_Deportes.class));
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity_Noticias_Politica.class));
                break;
            case R.id.button3:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity_Noticias_Economia.class));
                break;
            case R.id.button4:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity_Noticias_Entretencion.class));
                break;
        }
    }
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Deseas mostrar un "loading" aún en el splash screen?

Comment: Deseo mostrar el loading cada vez que se esté cargando la URL, nose si me explico

Comment: ok Rodrigo, simplemente debes tener un método o callback que indique esta preparada la reproducción en ese momento haces invisible el Progressbar, ve mi respuesta.

Comment: Exacto! @Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) { 
     miprogressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)     

}

Comment: Elena, me figura como 'never used', es decir que no se está utilizando, debo agregarlo a onCreate?

Comment: debes declarar el Progressbar y buscarlo en el layout con findViewById()...  agrega tu código! imagino tienes otra clase para la reproducción del Streaming

Comment: Introduje mi codigo final, porque no me resulta o yo no logro ver el progresbar en mi app, en qué puedo estar fallando?, muchas gracias

Comment: ese método public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)  no se esta ejecutando, revisa la actualización de mi respuesta se usa un listener setOnPreparedListener() y dentro se sobreescribe onPrepared(), :)

Comment: @Elenasys de verdad muchas gracias por sus respuesta, lamento que aún no me funcione lo que necesito, sucede que estoy probando por el momento con un mensaje Toast, y este mensaje aparece una vez cargado el url, es decir presiono play tarda por ejemplo 5 segundo en comenzar el sonido y una vez pasados esos 5 segundos y comenzada la trasmisión figura el mensaje Toast.

Comment: Te comento que el código lo dejé así, tal cual me lo indicaste.

mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                   //progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cargandooooooo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

Se entiende que el progressbar esta comentado y la linea del Toast no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si deseas mostrar un progressbar ("loading") mientras cargas tu video, simplemente agregalo dentro de un RelativeLayout y lo centras, lo pondras invisible cuando este preparada ó inicie la reproducción del video.

`setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` o `setVisibility(View.GONE)`

Este es un layout ejemplo:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/Load_rly_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/streamingVideoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />

    <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/mi_loading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Cuando el video esta preparado para reproducir es cuando puedes hacer invisible el ProgressBar:

```
...
...
//Bloque de coding para el streaming al cargar el activity
    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
...
...
```